# Getting http 500 response body with flex

Tags: apache-flex

I am using a `HttpService` object in flex to communicate with the server.
I am using java in the server (tomcat), and once an exception occurs the fault event listener in the flex is called.
I am passing data on the exception in the response body in a xml form.

The thing is the flex fault event does not read the data from the response.
How can i read the response body?

Comment: Isn't an HTTP 500 error a generic server problem?  I would assume that this means you have a misconfiguration issue w/ your web server or Java server.

Comment: It is a generic server problem, i use the response body to add details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience, you can't.  Flex turns any 400-599 response codes into a generic IOError and only gives the status code.  My understanding is that this is a browser-plugin limitation, but I'm not sure of the extent/reason.

The way we've gotten around it is that all 400-599's get wrapped as 200-OK with a response showing the details of the error.  I've heard many argue that this means Flex/Flash can never truly be a RESTful client.

Comment: You are correct, from what i have seen only IE supports reading the exception data. I also solved this by wrapping the response.